Web3 error: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')
i'm trying to listen to the ethereum chain for transactions on my usdt erc20 wallet address, using node.js and web3. Whenever usdt is sent into my wallet address, i intend to log the amount recieved in realtime.
This is my code:
const {Web3} = require('web3');
const USDT_ABI = require('erc-20-abi'); 

//My QuickNode WSS endpoint
const wssProviderUrl = 'wss://thrilling-orbital-lake.quiknode.pro/********/';

// Initialize Web3 with WebSocket provider
const web3Client = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider(wssProviderUrl));

// My wallet address
const yourAddress = '0x***********************';

// USDT contract address on Ethereum
const USDTContractAddress = '0xdAC17F958D2ee523aeeE4C20C7C1dE6e8FcB49aC';

/// Initialize the USDT contract
const USDTContract = new web3Client.eth.Contract(USDT_ABI, USDTContractAddress);

// Subscribe to Transfer events to your address
USDTContract.events.Transfer({ filter: { to: yourAddress } })
  .on('data', (event) => {
    const amount = event.returnValues.value;
    console.log(`Received ${web3Client.utils.fromWei(amount, 'mwei')} USDT to your wallet address!`);
  })
  .on('error', (error) => {
    console.error('Error subscribing to event:', error);
  });


But i keep getting this error:
  .on('error', (error) => {
  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'on')

How can i fix this please?
I expect my code to log the transaction details whenever i receive tokens.

First, make sure your web3 js version supports "on method"
then check if your subscription was successful before adding the event
const transferSubscription = USDTContract.events.Transfer({
    filter: { to: yourAddress }
 });

Then you can do this
 if (transferSubscription) {
  transferSubscription
    .on('data', (event) => {
      const amount = event.returnValues.value;
      console.log(`Go on and enter your message`);
    })
    .on('error', (error) => {
      console.error('Error :', error);
    });
} else {
  console.error('undefined subscription');
}

You can also validate your WebSocket provider , your abi and the address
